# Linux processes: CPU-intensive program questions [Bash Shell]

Tags: bash, operating-system, process

I'm trying to see some things about processes in Linux and I have some questions that I hope you could answer for me.

I did this little program to see how it acts:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=1
while [ true ]
do
  echo "Counter $count "
  count=$(( $count + 1 ))
done
```

Is just an **infinite loop**.

Now, when I execute the program and use the `top` command in the shell, that process is the one the consumes more CPU resources:

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND   
4037 lola    20   0  16880 1248 1028 R   80  0.0   0:33.42 memoryleak.sh
```

I let the program run for a time, but never exceeds 85% of CPU consumption, **why is that?** I guess that it is a mechanism of hygiene of the OP, but, if truth, which are the parameters to decide. Even more, the counter is still working, and, for what I see, could still work *ad infinitum*. **Why is the CPU-intensive program not crashing the CPU?**

Now, If I interrupt the process -sending a **STOP** signal-, and do a `ps aux` I get:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
lola       3896 24.4  0.0  16880  1248 pts/3    T    09:15   0:37 /bin/bash ./cpukilla.sh
```

**Why, after stopped the process, the CPU consumption is still 24%?** Should not be zero?

Any assistance would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: well, sorry for the "confusion" of the memory leak term. Never the less, it would not be technically a memory leak, because the **count** is consuming much memory without releasing it?

Comment: Why exactly do you think that's a memory leak?

Comment: Well, an application the consumes all the resources of the machine (maybe the term is not as precise as I should have used it). (In the book that I'm reading they use it with that approx sense)

Comment: No, a memory leak is gradually losing memory because you don't keep pointers for it. What you have here is simply a runaway process or CPU-intensive one. Modifying the question to suit.

Comment: could you suggest a little example in bash the demonstrate a memory leak? please

Comment: For a "leak", you'd be looking at something like `s = "" ; while [[ true ]] ; do s="xyzzy$s" ; done` although technically, that's not a leak, just every increasing usage.

Comment: Try the `htop` command to see what other processes are running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it never exceeds 85% of the CPU, that's because the OS has *other* things calling on its resources. Lots of processes run on a multi-tasking system and it's the job of the OS to keep them all playing nicely.

In fact, under Linux (for one), if your process consistently uses its entire timeslice (ie, not yielding early), its priority will be downgraded as "punishment".

A CPU-intensive program won't *crash* the operating system simply because the OS knows how to protect itself from such shenanigans :-)

As to the 24% figure, I'm not sure on that. It *may* be that the figure is based on program lifetime rather than the last few seconds, in which case it would reduce gradually (a series of `ps -aux` statements ten seconds apart would corroborate or destroy that theory, the former if it keeps reducing, that latter if it jumps up again).

The man page doesn't give a *lot* of detail on what the `%cpu` actually represents but does say:

> CPU usage is currently expressed as the percentage of time spent running during the entire lifetime of a process. This is not ideal, and it does not conform to the standards that ps otherwise conforms to. CPU usage is unlikely to add up to exactly 100%.

This *could* be read as being a figure calculated over a time period rather (eg, last five minutes) than instantaneous (last second).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this causes no memory leak at all. Maybe you're mistaken "memory leak" with another concept. Memory leak is when you allocate memory and fail to free it. Here you're not allocating any memory **directly**.

1. The kernel reserves time for every process, so no one gets "starved", and specially for itself, so it could schedule everything fine (btw, such a script would crash Windows'98 for example, where multitasking is poorly implemented).
2. Why would the CPU crash? This question makes no sense. It would work *ad infinitum*, yes.
3. [It is not running](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28712/among-ps-command-output-fields-cpu-isnt-the-actual-cpu-usage-of-the-process) (thanks geekosaur)

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28712/among-ps-command-output-fields-cpu-isnt-the-actual-cpu-usage-of-the-process

Answer (score 0):

Typically, memory leak refers to a situation wherein a chunk of memory is allocated to a program, and (normally due to programming error), that memory is never released by the program when it is done with it.  In actuality, your bash script here doesn't have a memory leak.

The OS will prevent the process from ever taking 100% control of the CPU.  Linux is a preemptive multitasking system; it will never relinquish control of the CPU.  The scheduler ensures that all processes that need a CPU timeslice get one.  Here is more on the Linux scheduler: 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-scheduler/

Sending a STOP signal doesn't terminate the process; it only suspends it.  Send a SIGCONT to have it continue.  If you terminate it, it will be removed from your process list.